# How to add to git an empty directory, whose content is automatically emptied by a script periodically?

Tags: git

I've got a `/static` directory, whose content is auto-generated by my scripts.

I need to include it into the repository, because this repository is an image for docker deployment environment and docker build scenario assumes that this directory is present.

So, if I just put a `.gitignore` or `.gitkeep` file in it, it will be swept next time my script auto-populates that directory. What do I do?

Comment: ... fix the script? :-)

Comment: Change the Docker build scenario to not assume the directory is present. Git is not a build nor deployment tool, ensuring empty directories exist after build and deployment is their job.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into parent's `.gitignore`

`echo "static/*" >> ../.gitignore`

Git can't track empty directories, that's why the `.gitkeep` files are used, it's more a convention then anything else. The name is arbitrary. So if you create `/static` and put there the `.gitkeep` file (or any other file) and then add the `static/*` record to the parent's `.gitignore`, you should be good.

Comment: The problem is that this `.gitkeep` is going to be cleaned by my script.

Answer (score 0):

You can not:

> Currently the design of the Git index (staging area) only permits files to be listed, and nobody competent enough to make the change to allow empty directories has cared enough about this situation to remedy it.
>   Directories are added automatically when adding files inside them. That is, directories never have to be added to the repository, and are not tracked on their own.
>   You can say "git add " and it will add the files in there.
>   If you really need a directory to exist in checkouts you should create a file in it. .gitignore works well for this purpose (there is also a tool MarkEmptyDirs using the .NET framework which allows you to automate this task); you can leave it empty or fill in the names of files you do not expect to show up in the directory.

[cite](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F)

There are some workarounds available to you though. The most common is add a `.gitkeep` or `.gitignore` file in that folder and forcing your scripts to not delete it.